# (un)signed short int (C)

Tags: c, literals, short

It has been established in another question on this website that there is no literal suffix for short in C and that one can do the following:

```
short Number = (short)1;
```

But what is the difference between casting it and not doing so:

```
short Number = 1;
```

Does it ever matter which you use and how does the compiler handle them differently?

Comment: When you declare a typed variable like this it is "automatically casted" to the said type, so there is no differences.

Comment: It does matter as the default literal is int, so the scope of the int is bigger as Mayarz said it is implicitly converted into short, however with high warning level the compiler will not like this (and will always like explicit casts).

Comment: @harper : *"depends on the mood of the compiler"*; that would suggest that it is not deterministic and likely to vary.  It may depend on the compiler implementation, the compiler version and compiler options, but not its "mood".  Either way both are valid C and semantically identical - a C compiler must accept either regardless of any diagnostics it may output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in effect of the implicit cast and the forced cast, the forced cast is largely *"documentary"* - it says *"I did this deliberately"*.

The explicit cast makes it clear to a potential maintainer, they the type is deliberately `short` and should not be changed to match the initialiser.  It may also serve to silence compiler or static analysis tool warnings.  However if you provide an initialiser that is too large for a short - it will silence any warning of that too.

The explicit cast is perhaps more useful in macro definitions such as:

```
#define DEFAULT_CONDITION ((short)1)

short condition = DEFAULT_CONDITION ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of the code is the same in both cases.

But some code checkers/compilers could warn if you assign an `int` to a `short` (with an implicit conversion).

Most tools I know don't do that for literal values though. They check if the known literal actually fits into the smaller type.